# problem using MAX argument in python with "FOR" loop

Tags: python

I need to perform this operation on some directories to get the most recent file, but there are times when the directory is empty, so I was getting the error about an empty array. Therefore, I have specified "default=None" in the MAX argument to get around that.
However, it then continues the script and tries to perform an operation on the files that it finds, but it's an empty array, there is nothing for it to do and it errors out with:
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

```
 import glob, os
 import datetime
 import shutil, os

 exchanges = ["bats","nyse']
 for ex in exchanges:
     csv_file_list = glob.glob(f"H:\\SQL_EXPORTS\\eod\\candles\\{ex}\\*.csv")
     latest_file = max(csv_file_list, key=os.path.getctime, default=None)
     print(latest_file)
     if len(["csv_file_list"]) > 0:
         latest_file = max(csv_file_list, key=os.path.getctime)
     else:
         print("no files in directory")
     path = f'H:\\SQL_EXPORTS\\eod\\candles\\{ex}\\'
     fileBaseName = os.path.basename(latest_file).split('.')[0]
```

it is throwing that error after trying to interpret what to do on the last line of the code show above. What I need to do I think, is to, instead of  the 'else: print("no files in directory"). I want to have it go to the bottom of the "FOR" loop. Then it can start over for another stock exchange. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: You start the string `nyse` with a double quote, and end it with a single, seems like you've got a syntax error there.

Comment: Check if `csv_file_list` is empty, and if it is, abort the loop before calling `max()`.

Comment: CollinD, that typo was just here in this example, not in the real code. John Gordon, thanks, this is what I did and I got it working. I dont see any way to accept the answer. No green check box to check